# Llenar segundo ComboBox según lo seleccionado en el primero (java y Mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, combobox

os decribo lo que tengo hecho a ver si alguien me puede decir cómo puedo soluccionar mi problema.
Tengo una BBDD en MySql con 3 tablas(cliente, vehiculo, reserva). Las tablas se relaccionan de la siguiente manera: vehiculo tiene la FKdni del cliente y reserva tiene las Fkdni y la FKmatricula. Hasta aquí todo bien (por lo menos desde Workbench).
En Java tengo las tres mismas clases para agregar clientes, vehiculos y reservas a esos clientes. Mediante ComboBox me traigo los dni y las matrículas, pero claro me las traigo sin filtros,o lo que es lo mismo, cuando trae todas las matrículas no las trae asociadas a un dni.
Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Cómo puedo hacer que para que cuando selecciono un dni en un ComboBox me traiga las matrículas asociadas a ese dni en el ComboBox de matrículas?

Lo que he había pensado es capturar el valor seleccionado en el ComboDni y meterlo en el select del ComboMatriculas, pero no sé si esa es la solucción o se tiene que hacer de otra manera ni tampoco sé si eso se puede hacer y si me va a traer algún dato.
Dejo por aquí el código del ComboMatrícula por si me podéis explicar cómo hacerlo.
Muchas gracias por adelantado.

```
    public void llenarComboMatriculaVehiculo() {
    DefaultComboBoxModel modelo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    ConexionMySql cc = new ConexionMySql();
    Connection cn = cc.conectar();

    try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet datos = st.executeQuery("Select matricula from vehiculo");
        while (datos.next()) {
            modelo.addElement(datos.getString("matricula"));

        }
        cn.close();
        cboMatriculaVehiculo.setModel(modelo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como Llenar Textbox Java dependiendo del valor de 2 Combobox?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36580/como-llenar-textbox-java-dependiendo-del-valor-de-2-combobox)